# how to get sum from first to many rows it depends on request mysql

Tags: mysql

Table.Bank

```
id     debit     credit            sumdebit                sumcredit
1        5         0               I need here
2        0         5               the sum of
3        15        0               first three
4        0         15              rows of debit 
5        30        0               or 4 rows 
6        0         30              it depend on 
                                request
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is very hard to decipher, a request for a Summation would use an aggregate operator and would look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(some_attribute)
FROM SOME_RELATION
```